# Extend ELMAH to include another viewer hitting a different table

Tags: elmah

I've been doing a little tweaking of the SQL-side of ELMAH to provide basic logging capabilities to my MVC app.

I changed ELMAH_LogError to test the TYPE field for text sent by my App and, if found, inserts to a different table that i'd created by 'Script As'

It was reasonably easy to simply create a new table because I didn't try to rename any fields. The structure is identical to the original. Any chance this same principle (same structure/different table name) could be (easily) extended to providing a new 'Logger.axd' that would provide viewing of my newly created table?

thx

Comment: It should be trivial to write your own axd handler to view that table.  I'm not exactly sure what your question is?

Comment: Exactly that. I'm not a competent enough .net coder to gauge how hard it would be. Just looking for confirmation that ELMAH's source is as straight-forward-to-edit as the TSQL was.

Comment: ...would be happy to mark your comment as answered...

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?